# TelemetryProcessor not called without an InstrumentationKey?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've created a class derived from **ITelemetryProcessor**, so I can capture telemetry data during a unit test of a C# .Net Class Library. Being a unit test, there is no **InstrumentationKey** provided as unit tests should have no network dependencies. (I cannot factor the telemetry to an injected interface.)

I create and use **TelemetryClient's** and log custom events during the unit test methods. However, I noticed my **Process()** method was not getting called when I logged telemetry items.

After doing some experimentation, I realized that if set an **InstrumentationKey** to a dummy Guid, then my **Processor()** method started to get called.

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Question: why should I need to provide an InstrumentationKey in order for processors to be invoked?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 0):

TelemetryProcessor's are meant to apply additional processing/filtering to telemetry items before being sent to AI. If there is no ikey, then there is no point sending to AI as it will not be accepted anyway. Why run overhead of running all processors.